# MongoDB Java nested documents not accessible using dots in key name

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

When using the MongoDB API in Java, I am trying to retrieve the value of `two` in a document that looks like this:

```
data-id: "1234"
one:
    two: "three"
```

And I am running this:

```
MongoCollection<Document> documents = ...;
Document document = documents.find(Filters.eq("data-id", "1234")).first(); // Not null
document.get("one"); // Not null
document.get("one.two"); // This is null
((Document) document.get("one")).get("two"); // Not null
```

After spending some time reading documentation and other Stack Overflow questions, I learned that using dots in the key name (like `one.two` for the key) should work, but it isn't for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After spending some time reading documentation and other Stack
>   Overflow questions, I learned that using dots in the key name (like
>   one.two for the key) should work, but it isn't for me.

The dot-notation works fine when used within a `find` method's query filter. For example,

```
Document document = collection.find(Filters.eq("one.two", "three")).first();
System.out.println(document);    // prints the returned document
```

or its `mongo` shell equivalent:

```
db.collection.find( { "one.two": "three" } )
```

The [Document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html) class's  `get()` method takes an `Object` (a String key) as a parameter and returns an `Object`.

Consider the code:

```
Document doc = coll.find(eq("data-id", "1234")).first();
System.out.println(doc);
```

The output `Document{{_id=1.0, data-id=1234, one=Document{{two=three}}}}` shows there are *three* keys: `_id`, `data-id` and `one`. Note there is *no* key named as `one.two`. The key `two` is *within the sub-dcument* of the document with the key `one`.

So, from your code:

```
document.get("one.two");    // This is null ((Document)
document.get("one")).get("two"); // Not null
```

The first statement returns `null`, and the next one returns `three` (the String value). Both are *correct* results and that is the behavior of the `Document`class API.

You should use the method `getEmbedded` to access the embedded field `one.two`. So, replace `document.get("one.two")` with

```
document.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("one", "two"), String.class)
```

The result is "three", as expected.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB allows dots in the field names.

```
document.get("one.two");
```

would actually be looking for a field like

```
data-id: "1234"
"one.two": "three"
```

where "one.two" is a simple field, not an embedded document.

Comment: MongoDB can't have keys with dots in them... But I get what you mean.

Comment: actually, starting in version 3.6, it does allow dots in the field name.  See [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)