# Retrieving ObjectID on MongoDB sub-document using Java driver methods

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongo-java-driver

Consider this document structure (employees). It contains a reference to the department document embedded within it named "deptno" which stores a reference to the department document.

```java
    ali@MongoDB>db.employees.find().pretty()
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e907ad23997181dde06e8fc"),
            "empno" : 7839,
            "ename" : "KING",
            "mgrno" : 0,
            "hiredate" : "1990-05-09",
            "sal" : 100000,
            "deptno" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9065f53997181dde06e8f8")
            },
            "username" : "none",
            "password" : "none",
            "is_admin" : "N",
            "is_approver" : "Y",
            "is_manager" : "Y",
            "user_role" : "AP",
            "admin_approval_received" : "Y",
            "active" : "Y",
            "created_date" : "2020-04-10",
            "updated_date" : "2020-04-10",
            "application_usage_log" : [
                    {
                            "logged_in_as" : "AP",
                            "log_in_date" : "2020-04-10"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

Using the following statements to retrieve the deptno - _id field.

```java
    FindIterable<Document> docs = emp_collection.find();
        for (Document d : docs)
        { 
            System.out.println("Employee Details ...");
            System.out.println("Employee # : " + d.getDouble("empno"));
            System.out.println("Employee Name : " + d.getString("ename"));
            System.out.println("Manager # : " + d.getDouble("mgrno"));
            System.out.println("Hiredate : " + d.getString("hiredate"));
            System.out.println("Salary : " + d.getDouble("sal"));

            //Retrive the department details using the ObjectId stored in the Employee document. 
            oid = d.getObjectId("deptno");  
            query = eq("_id",oid);
            FindIterable<Document> dept_docs = dept_collection.find(query);

This statement -- oid = d.getObjectId("deptno")-- produces an error saying , although getObjectId() is designated to return ObjectId.
==================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bson.Document cannot be cast to class org.bson.types.ObjectId (org.bson.Document and org.bson.types.ObjectId are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.bson.Document.getObjectId(Document.java:323)
    at MongoDBExample.main(MongoDBExample.java:45)
===================
```

How do I retrieve the "_id" field from the deptno sub-document ?.

[image: Eclipse IDE - Balloon help for getObjectID() method]

[image: getObjectId()_Cast_error]

Comment: See this post's answer: [MongoDB Java nested documents not accessible using dots in key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144095/mongodb-java-nested-documents-not-accessible-using-dots-in-key-name/61151543#61151543).

Comment: Thank you Prasad. That was really helpful information.

Comment: @Ali if the answer was helpful please mark it approved. So, that we can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made use of the following and it helped

```
oid = d.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("deptno","_id"), ObjectId.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there...

The problem is

> oid = d.getObjectId("deptno");

This will return the Document object, not an ObjectId. Hence, the exception was thrown.

So, replace it with:

```
oid = d.get("deptno",Document.class).getObjectId("_id");
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you Vijay.  The in-place documentation that appears at the cursor position on the Eclipse IDE says that this method getObjectId() returns a ObjectId. Am I reading that incorrectly. Can you please check the attached image and help me understand what the signature is trying to convey ?.

Comment: Hello Vijay, Tried to make use of the suggestion. But still the same error shows up. Please see the screenshot named [getObjectId()_Cast_error]

Comment: Yes, it will return ObjectId. it works fine if your document contains ObjectId at the root level.

Comment: in your case, it is embedded ``` "deptno" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e9065f53997181dde06e8f8")
        }```

Comment: Thats right, it is an embedded document. What should be the alternative in this case ?

Comment: You would have kept it on root level. ``` "_id" : ObjectId("5e9065f53997181dde06e8f8") ```

Comment: Made use of the following and it helped                                                                                                            
                    oid = d.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("deptno","_id"), ObjectId.class);

Comment: that was great :)