# Access Subdocument Values in MongoDB Using Java FindIterable

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to print out a key value in a subdocument and I have having trouble landing on the proper format to do it.

The statements below print out the document:

```
FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(query).projection(fields(include("user.ip_address"))).limit(5);

for (Document document : documents) {
    System.out.println(document.get("user"));
}

/* Output */

Document{{ip_address=10.0.0.1}}
Document{{ip_address=10.0.0.2}}
Document{{ip_address=10.0.0.3}}
Document{{ip_address=10.0.0.4}}
Document{{ip_address=10.0.0.5}}
```

I've tried:

`System.out.println(document.get("user.ip_address"))` (prints all nulls)

`System.out.println(document.getObjectId("user", "ip_address"))`

`System.out.println(document.getObjectId(new Document("user", "ip_address")))` (prints all nulls)

and others that IntelliJ errors out on.

Edit:

This does work below, but it seems that there should be tidier way to do it especially as the nested documents increase.

```
Document ip = (Document) document.get("user");
System.out.println(ip.get("ip_address"));
```

Also, I have no idea why I need to cast it to a Document when it is a Document to begin with.

```
System.out.println(document.get("user").getClass());
class org.bson.Document
```

Comment: Here is a post with similar question: [MongoDB Java nested documents not accessible using dots in key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144095/mongodb-java-nested-documents-not-accessible-using-dots-in-key-name/61151543#61151543)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that post. Helped very much.